# Highlight (shade) plot background in specific time range

Tags: r, plot, highlight

On a generic plot, with time on the x-axis, I would like to highlight a period of some specific years.

How can I bestly do this? My idea is for example a light yellow bar for the highlighted years, behind the plot of course.

The plot code I have now:

```
pdf("temperature_imfs_big_interm5.pdf", width=6, height=8);
par(mfrow=c(temperature$bigEmdIm5$nimf+1,1), mar=c(2,1,2,1))
for(i in 1:temperature$bigEmdIm5$nimf) {
    plot(timeline$big, temperature$bigEmdIm5$imf[,i], type="l", xlab="", ylab="", ylim=range(temperature$bigEmdIm5$imf[,i]), axes=FALSE, main=paste(i, "-th IMF", sep=""))#; abline(h=0)
  axis.POSIXct(side=1, at=tickpos$big)
}
plot(timeline$big, temperature$bigEmdIm5$residue, xlab="", ylab="", axes=FALSE, main="residue", type="l")
axis.POSIXct(side=1, at=tickpos$big)
dev.off();
```

Where temperature$bigEmdIm5 is the output of emperical mode decompostion. The data is in months, so I would like to higlight 01/1950 until 12/1950 for example.

Comment: Can you please put the data somewhere, or add a command to create a mock data.frame so that we can actually help you?

Comment: Also, if your x-axis data is of class POSIXct then calling 'axis(side=1,at=tickpos)' should do and is a better idiom than to explicitly force a dispatch.

Comment: rcs: Hm, maybe I am spoiled from too much `zoo` and `xts`. Does it fail even when you use `Date` instead of the higher-res. `POSIXct`?  Anyway, thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @Dirk: yes, also numeric values when `Date` is used

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using alpha transparency:

```
x <- seq(as.POSIXct("1949-01-01", tz="GMT"), length=36, by="months")
y <- rnorm(length(x))

plot(x, y, type="l", xaxt="n")
rect(xleft=as.POSIXct("1950-01-01", tz="GMT"),
     xright=as.POSIXct("1950-12-01", tz="GMT"),
     ybottom=-4, ytop=4, col="#123456A0") # use alpha value in col
idx <- seq(1, length(x), by=6)
axis(side=1, at=x[idx], labels=format(x[idx], "%Y-%m"))
```

[image]

or plot highlighted region behind lines:

```
plot(x, y, type="n", xaxt="n")
rect(xleft=as.POSIXct("1950-01-01", tz="GMT"),
     xright=as.POSIXct("1950-12-01", tz="GMT"),
     ybottom=-4, ytop=4, col="lightblue")
lines(x, y)
idx <- seq(1, length(x), by=6)
axis(side=1, at=x[idx], labels=format(x[idx], "%Y-%m"))
box()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that uses [**zoo**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo) simply because that makes the subsetting easy. You could do the same with standard indexing as well:

```
## create a long monthly sequence and a sub-sequence
months <- seq( as.Date("1950-01-01"), as.Date("2009-12-12"), by="month")
subset <- seq( as.Date("1970-01-01"), as.Date("1979-12-31"), by="month")

## generate some random values
set.seed(42)
values <- cumsum(rnorm(length(months)))

## plot as a zoo object, overlay a gray background and overplot a line in red
library(zoo)
Z <- zoo(values, months)
plot(Z)
rect(xleft=head(subset,1), xright=tail(subset,1),
     ybottom=par("usr")[3], ytop=par("usr")[4],
     density=NA, col="lightgray")
lines(Z[subset], col='red')
box()
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [eddelbuettel.com](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/misc/plotRegionExample.png))</sub>

By using `par("usr")` we avoid the need for explicit values for upper and lower region marks. And the `zoo` indexing makes finding the start- and endpoints easy. This would work the same way for data in different time resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `chartSeries()` function in `quantmod` with an `xts` timeSeries and the `addTA()` function to add the background highlighting:

```
addTA(xts(rep(TRUE,length(times)), times), on=-1, col="#333333", border=NA)
```

Comment: For this solution I would have to change my plotting command I guess

Comment: If you want a specific response, you need to give more detail.  What's your plotting command?