# How do I highlight an observation's bin in a histogram in R

Tags: r, histogram

I want to create a histogram from a number of observations (i.e. d <- c(1,2.1,3.4,4.5) ) and then highlight the bin that a particular observation falls in, such that I have an output that looks like this:
[image]

how do I do this in R?

Comment: You might also get some ideas from this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915001/highlighting-specific-values-in-r-plot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expanding on dangerstat's answer, here is a little function that will automatically find which bin contains the value that you want to highlight:

```
highlight <- function(x, value, col.value, col=NA, ...){
   hst <- hist(x, ...)
   idx <- findInterval(value, hst$breaks)
   cols <- rep(col, length(hst$counts))
   cols[idx] <- col.value
   hist(x, col=cols, ...)
}
```

Now

```
x <- rnorm(100)
highlight(x, 1.2, "red")
```

will highlight the bin with 1.2 in it in red.

Answer (score 5):

```
x = rnorm(100)
hist(x,br=10,col=c(rep(0,9),1))
```

Clearly this will color the last column so tweak the col= bit for your needs

Thanks

dangerstat

Comment: thats how i would do it. note, for typical colors like red and blue, you can enter in a string instead of the number: `col=c("red", "blue", 9)`