# How to highlight bin of observation in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

How to highlight the **entire bar** in which the **observations** obs.A and obs.B respectively **are being allocated** using ggplot? The exact [same thing has been done for the regular hist() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127926/how-do-i-highlight-an-observations-bin-in-a-histogram-in-r) but what is the ggplot way?

Below some code to illustrate

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(Var=c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50)), Value=round(rnorm(100,10,2),0))
obs.A<-8
obs.B<-10
ggplot(data)+
  geom_histogram(aes(x=Value))+
  facet_grid(Var ~ .)
```

Edit: It needs to work for large and small sample sizes and really only highlight one and all of the bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one ggplot way is to build it into the dataframe used for plotting:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(Var=c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50)), Value=round(rnorm(100,10,2),0))
obs.A<-8
obs.B<-10

data$color <- ifelse(data$Var == "A" & data$Value == obs.A, T, F)
data$color <- ifelse(data$Var == "B" & data$Value == obs.B, T, data$color)

ggplot(data)+
    geom_histogram(aes(x=Value, fill = color))+
    facet_grid(Var ~ .)
```

[image]

Note this works easily for your test case because the range for `data$Value` is 5-16 and the default for `geom_histogram()` is `bins = 30`. If you wanted to make it more transferable you would want to set `geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)` or set `data$color` based on bins, something like this:

```
data <- data.frame(Var=c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50)), Value=round(rnorm(100,10,10),0)) # bigger sd
obs.A<-8
obs.B<-10

data$cuts <- cut(data$Value, 30, labels = F)
A_colored_cuts <- unique(data$cuts[data$Value == obs.A])
data$color <- ifelse(data$Var == "A" & data$cuts == A_colored_cuts, T, F)

B_colored_cuts <- unique(data$cuts[data$Value == obs.B])
data$color <- ifelse(data$Var == "B" & data$cuts == B_colored_cuts, T, data$color)


ggplot(data)+
    geom_histogram(aes(x=Value, fill = color))+
    facet_grid(Var ~ .)
```

[image]

EDIT: For larger sample sizes, we would want to use the second option outlined above and specify `geom_histogram(boundary = .5)`, since we want the bin breaks on integers.

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(Var=c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50)), Value=round(rnorm(10000,10,10),0))
#use code chunk 2 above
ggplot(data)+
    geom_histogram(aes(x=Value, fill = color), boundary = .5)+
    facet_grid(Var ~ .)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that is a great approach, however, if the number of binned elements is large (try using rnorm(10000,10,10) it will only color part of the bar, or possibly more than one bars. Can this be improved?

Comment: Thank you again, but is there no more direct way to just get the bin of an observation and have ggplot identify that bin and assign a different color?

Comment: you could specify the breaks directly to `geom_histogram(break = ...)` as a `numeric vector`. If you wanted to do this you could parse the output of `cut(labels = T,...)` to get the break values. To me that parsing route seems like extra work, for the same plots...but it's your time and your call

Answer (score 1):

We can try this to have desired the highlighting for any size of data (we may need to adjust the `bindwith` with the data size for the bar chart to look prettier and more informative):

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(12345)
data <- data.frame(Var=c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50)), Value=round(rnorm(100,10,2),0))
obs.A<-8
obs.B<-10
cond <- (data$Var=='A' & data$Value == obs.A)|(data$Var=='B' & data$Value == obs.B)
binwidth <- 0.25
ggplot(data)+
  geom_histogram(data=data[!cond,], aes(x=Value), binwidth=binwidth) + 
  geom_histogram(data=data[cond,], aes(x=Value), fill='red', binwidth=binwidth) + 
  facet_grid(Var ~ .)
```

[image]

```
set.seed(12345)
data <- data.frame(Var=c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50)), Value=round(rnorm(10000,10,10),0))
obs.A<-8
obs.B<-10
cond <- (data$Var=='A' & data$Value == obs.A)|(data$Var=='B' & data$Value == obs.B)
binwidth <- 0.5
ggplot(data)+
  geom_histogram(data=data[!cond,], aes(x=Value), binwidth=binwidth) + 
  geom_histogram(data=data[cond,], aes(x=Value), fill='red', binwidth=binwidth) + 
  facet_grid(Var ~ .)
```

[image]

Comment: Its a good approach. But the data is far too large and dispersed to just chose binwidth values that happen to be small enough. Is there any other way?

Comment: we can use `binwidth 1` too for the last example, the histogram will look less sparse.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the conditions inside `geom_histogram` for the aesthetics `fill`. We remove the oversized legend with `theme(legend.position = "none")`

```
# Example 1
set.seed(12345)
data <- data.frame(Var = c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 50)), Value = round(rnorm(100, 10, 2), 0))
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x = Value, 
                     fill = Value == 8 & Var == "A" | Value == 10 & Var == "B"), binwidth=0.5) +
  facet_grid(Var ~ .) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

```
# Example 2
set.seed(12345)
data <- data.frame(Var = c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 50)), Value = round(rnorm(10000, 10, 10), 0))
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x = Value, 
                     fill = Value == 8 & Var == "A" | Value == 10 & Var == "B"), binwidth = 0.5) +
  facet_grid(Var ~ .) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

If we would like to assign different colours, we use `scale_fill_manual`:

```
# Example3
set.seed(12345)
data <- data.frame(Var = c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 50)), Value = round(rnorm(100, 10, 2), 0))
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x = Value, 
                     fill = Value == 8 & Var == "A" | Value == 10 & Var == "B"), binwidth=0.5) +
  facet_grid(Var ~ .) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey45", "red"))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]