# R - Interactively show where a single observation is placed in a histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am using R and I would like to show a histogram chart which highlights the bar/column that a particular value is bucketed into. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127926/how-do-i-highlight-an-observations-bin-in-a-histogram-in-r) link shows how to do it base R. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792233/how-to-highlight-bin-of-observation-in-ggplot?noredirect=1&lq=1) shows how it's done in ggplot. However, I need it to be interactive and possibly once the mouse hovers over the bar of interest (or selected), some details that i can specify are provided.

I looked into googlevis and dygraphs. It would look great in ggplot but I need it to be interactive. My plan is to put it into shiny or rmarkdown

Comment: Did you check plotly already?

Comment: I did, in general I stay away from plotly because I need the chart for commercial purposes, and I am not too sure I can freely do this with plotly.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend rAmCharts for iteractivity and possibility to customize with js
Check https://datastorm-open.github.io/introduction_ramcharts/ for more details

Comment: I did not know ramcharts existed. Shame on me - it looks beautiful