# Highlighting specific ranges on a Graph in R

Tags: r, graph, highlight

```
library(season)
plot(CVD$yrmon, CVD$cvd, type = 'o',pch = 19,ylab = 'Number of CVD deaths per month',xlab = 'Time')
```

if i wanted to highlight a region of the graph based on x values say from 1994-1998 how do i do this?

Any thought would be appreciated 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you could place a rectangle on the region of interest:

```
rect(xleft=1994,xright = 1998,ybottom=range(CVD$cvd)[1],ytop=range(CVD$cvd)[2], density=10, col = "blue")
```

[image: Maybe something like this]

Comment: You may want the `rect` to cover the full y-range .. `rect(xleft=1994,xright = 1998,ybottom=par("usr")[3], ytop=par("usr")[4], density=10, col = "blue")` . [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915001/highlighting-specific-values-in-r-plot?/1915512#1915512)

Answer (score 1):

You could just color the points in that range another color,

```
plot(CVD$yrmon, CVD$cvd, type = 'o',pch = 19,ylab = 'Number of CVD deaths per month',xlab = 'Time')
points(cvd ~ yrmon, type="o", pch=19, col="red", 
       data=CVD[CVD$yrmon >= 1994 & CVD$yrmon <= 1998,])
```

[image]

Comment: i tried that but all the points went to red. maybe i typed something wrong?